# A hint to this integral would be appreciated!

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

given $ a,b $ belong to the set of real numbers and $ a+b=4  ,  a<2 $ and let $ g(x) $ be an increasing function defined over the real numbers such that  . Then prove that $  \int_{0}^{a} g(x) dx + \int_{0}^{b} g(x) dx $ increases as $ b-a $ increases.  now let me introduce my approach to the problem as given $ a<2 $ we assume $ a=2-t $  for some +ve $ t  $ this would lead to $ b=2+t $ and we now express $ b-a $ as $ 2t $ and now the problem reduces to :- $ \int_{0}^{2-t} g(x) dx + \int_{0}^{2+t } g(x) dx $ which is a single variable function  let it be $ h(t) $ and differentiating it  with respect to $ t $ should  yield $ {h}' (t) =  g(2+t) - g(2-t) $ but I am unable to continue ahead  so I would love  to get hints and suggestions . Please help!  I also know that $ {h}' (t)$ is an odd function and that $ b-a = 2t  $ is an increasing function !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$h'(t) \geq 0$ as $g$ is an increasing function. Hence as $b-a$ increases so does $h$.

Comment: Got it aren't you suggesting that as $2-t$  < $ 2+t $ so $ {h}' (t)$ should be greater than zero  as g(x) is increasing

Comment: But still what you suggested doesn't seem right to me please give a more detailed hint